# using wordpress for portfolio and posts

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

i started playing wordpress few months a go and a created a blog
http://aurelkurtula.co.uk/blog/?page_id=2

currently there are no posts, but it will look similar to the link above.anyway, now i started to develop a portfolio theme using word-press, (i can only post one link)

the two themes are similar, so i was wondering if you could give me some advice on how to link this two themes together under one theme.

the only way i'm thinking about is something like this

```
<a href="#?type=blog">goto blog</a>
<a href="#?type=portfolio">goto portfolio</a> 
$type = $_get[type];
if(type = "blog"){   run ALL the blog head, body, sidebar and its style}
if
```

(type = "portfolio"){   run ALL the blog head, body and its style}

i have not tried it - but i guess am asking for "the best practice" advice.

i know that this is not the kind of question i should ask in a technical based forum, but i would really appreciate you help and advise

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. It sounds like you want a different theme/style for different pages, correct?

If the two are similar enough, you could use [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates). Alternately, if the two pages/sections are completely different themes, you could use the [Page Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-theme/) WordPress plugin to specify a specific theme for individual pages.

Comment: hi dennis, i'm trying the page theme but not 100% sure how to use it
maybe you could help me where im going wrong:

on the dashboard, i created a page, selected the theme i wanted for that page (fine) though when i view it - instead of displaying the homepage of the theme - it showed a blank page ( again, understandable as the page i created is blank, but it did get the background style) 

now i copied the code from the index.php (of that theme) and pasted it to the new page i created)

the php is coming up as if i wrote it using the visual mode (the php is not recognized) 

thanks for ur help

Comment: Worked ok for me. Did you follow the installation instructions: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-theme/installation/ ?

You shouldn't need to be changing any code to use the plugin.

Are you getting any PHP Errors?

Comment: I had forgot that i had a similar problem before, where if i used the same loop from the index page into another page - it did not work (am not good at explaning it but this way another thread i opened for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593112/wordpress-featured-posts 

but, yes the plug-in works perfectly - thanks for answering my question :)

Comment: i'm sorry - i noticed another problem - now i have the two themes, when i am on the portfolio page, when i click on the read more links on the page, it take me to the first (default) styled page, rather than continuing on the same style, again is there a way to have a second single.php page - so that the two different styles can work fully - thanks